# PHP split string

Tags: php

Hey how can I split string into 2 string, exemple:

```
$ipadd = "192.168.1.60";
```

From here I want to print 2 result, 
 one is: 192.168.1
 secend is:60

Always split by the last point and print 2 string.

Comment: `explode()`,`substr()` .., there are multiple options depending on particular requirements

Comment: Tried googling it? Or went on Php.net and switched on the brain? (Hint: split and put together all except the last)

Comment: @Jonasw ad.: for removing the last one, use `array_pop()`

Comment: @bwoebi: i think it doesnt make a difference because you have to convert the array back into a string

Comment: @Jonasw I meant like `$a=explode(...);$end=array_pop($a);$start=implode($a);`

Comment: @bwoebi: oh never heard of implode. Always used a for loop ( $string=$string..$array[$counter]). Good to know :)

Comment: @bwoebi: thats allready an good answer isnt it? ;)

Comment: @Jonasw thank you I used with: explode().  $spitIP = explode(".","192.168.1.60");
  $IP = $spitIP[0] . "." . $spitIP[1] . "." . $spitIP[2];

Comment: @user... : no worries. Wasnt to difficult wasnt it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after the last period:

```
echo substr(strrchr($ipadd, '.'), 1);
```

To get everything before it, you first need the position:

```
$pos = strrpos($ipadd, '.');
echo substr($ipadd, 0, $pos);
```

Comment: Thanks, Its great !